# Dynamic object creation and const_set

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create enum - like java analog.  I've this module.

```
module Enum

  def self.included(base)
    super
    base.extend(Enum)
    base.private_class_method :new
  end

  def enum(key, fields = {}, &class_body)

    value = Class.new(self) do
      fields.each_with_index do |item, i|
        define_singleton_method(item.first.to_s.downcase) { item.last }
        define_singleton_method("order") { i }
      end
    end

    self.const_set key, value        
  end

end
```

and

```
class TestEnum
  include Enum

  enum :TEST, value: 1
end
```

When I tried to

```
>> TestEnum::TEST.is_a? TestEnum
false <-
```

I've got this. Why? I expected to see 'true'.
But

```
>> TestEnum::TEST.ancestors
TestEnum::TEST.ancestors
[TestEnum::TEST, TestEnum, Enum, Object
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your use case? If it's merely to define an enum, you can use a Set with symbols.

Answer (score 2):

`obj.is_a? C` is true if `C` is the class of `obj`, or a module included by `obj`'s class, or one of the superclasses of the class of `obj`. It is used on *instances*, not *subclasses*.

```
class A; end
class B < A; end
b = B.new
b.is_a? A   # => true
```

If you want to know if a *class* is a subclass of another given class, simply use `ancestors.include?`.